# My river water won't flow at steady rate, any solution? (found it)

Tags: fluid-simulation, mantaflow

[image]

*(edit : i've found what worked for me, check below if ure interested)*

**Im trying to make** a steady river flow. It's actually just water flowing "horizontally" from the start (unlike my gif), but idk i've spent hours trying to do this, changing value, baking, freeing data, rinse and repeating tens of times without much result :(

**What i did** was basically making the ground and riverside as effectors, then i made a vertical plane mesh as inflow (with the correct normal orientation). After that, i put a big box with the side close to the start & end of my river as the domain.

**I tried** changing the inflow mesh with a cube instead of plane, tried checking and unchecking "is planar", changing resolution from 32 to 64.
**I also tried** changing the initial velocity (which i think might be the solution for this)... source velocity from 1 to 3 to 10 to 20, normal value from 0 to 5, 10, 50, 100, even 800 as i didnt know which value did what, initial Y velocity too from 0 m/s to 2, 5, 10. And permutations of those tweaks as well to no avail.

**Here is my blend file** if u guys wanna take a look, it's 34mb though :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ck0zCwZ73lhhpn9O1ZsssvC-MICtReIK/view?usp=sharing

Thank you for your time, genuinely appreciate anyone helping me.

(Ah and excuse my english, it's not my first language :D)

Comment: Unless you need to have the water splashing or something, its probably best to just try and fake it somehow.

Comment: i do need the physic tho, this is for an archimedes screw project, the fluid supposedly goes into a helix pipe in the middle of the river

Comment: if you are satisfied with this kind of flow...i would write an answer how i did it. https://youtu.be/m5leOAmASuE

Comment: @Chris is it possible for the water to be higher (or deeper)? i think one of my earlier flow looks like that too

Answer (score 1):

idk if im allowed to answer my own question, but i think ive found the solution.
not sure which one made it work but here u go

change the plane shape into cube,
uncheck the "is planar" in the inflow mesh,
choose inflow instead of geometry,
surface emmision 1
for initial velocity,
0 source, 0 normal, initial Y* coordinate 7.1 m/s

for Y*, change it to the direction that ur river is flowing to.
hope it helps